# Axios request cross-origin error with vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, axios, cors, webpack-dev-server

I test with google translate interface.(https://translate.google.cn/translate_a/xxxxx)
I'm using axios to request data.
my vue.config.js is here:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://translate.google.cn/translate_a',
      changeOrigin: true,
      ws: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my request code is here:

```
this.$axios.get(url, {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

And I also set in main.js(I'm using Vue.js)

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api'
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

Here are two conditions I have met:

1. I use `devServer` proxy to request normal when `yarn serve`, but after I run `yarn build` and run my dist files with `anywhere`, it shows error. The request url becomes `http://172.20.10.3:8000/api/single?xxxxxx`.
2. Due to 1, I manually set request url as `https://translate.google.cn/translate_a/single/xxxxxx`, but it will cause CORS error both in dev and in prod mode.

I did not found a good way to solve this problem, is it a problem of webpack or vue or axios? Or is there any backend setting to allow you request with devServer, but after you bundle it, you can not use it?

Answer (score -1):

The devServer is just for local development when your backend and frontend are running on different ports (or container etc.).
The devServer just help you locally to avoid CORS problems.

The browser is stopping requests to other domains.
Please read some documentations about CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Can I request like devServer in production?